# Update all instances of key inside nested JSON array

Tags: json, jsonb, json-path, cockroachdb

I'm trying to update a complex JSON document stored in a table in CockroachDB.

The CockroachDB query language is mostly Postgres compatible except for the lack of procedural code, so a Postgres answer without user functions or explicit loops will most likely work. The below sample code is also Postgres-compatible.

Among other things that make the document complex are that it contains nested arrays and some redundant structures.

The table and document are similar to the following:

```
  table_name |                      create_statement
-------------+--------------------------------------------------------------
  foo        | CREATE TABLE public.foo (
                 id INT8 NOT NULL,
                  data JSONB NOT NULL
              );

> insert into foo (id, data)
values(1, '{
    "foo": {
        "bar": {
            "bar": [
                {
                    "fields": [
                        {
                            "things": [],
                            "key": "something",
                            "value": ""
                        },
                        {
                            "things": [],
                            "key": "somethingelse",
                            "value": "1"
                        },
                        {
                            "things": [],
                            "key": "color",
                            "value": "pink"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": "ALL",
                    "fields": [
                          {
                            "things": [],
                            "key": "something",
                            "value": ""
                        },
                        {
                            "things": [],
                            "key": "somethingelse",
                            "value": "1"
                        },
                        {
                            "things": [],
                            "key": "color",
                            "value": "white"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": "1",
                    "fields": [
                          {
                            "things": [],
                            "key": "something",
                            "value": ""
                        },
                        {
                            "things": [],
                            "key": "somethingelse",
                            "value": "1"
                        },
                        {
                            "things": [],
                            "key": "color",
                            "value": "green"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": "ALL",
                    "fields": [
                                            {
                            "things": [],
                            "key": "something",
                            "value": ""
                        },
                        {
                            "things": [],
                            "key": "somethingelse",
                            "value": "1"
                        },
                        {
                            "things": [],
                            "key": "color",
                            "value": "red"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}');

> select jsonb_pretty(data) from foo;
                     jsonb_pretty
-------------------------------------------------------
  {
      "foo": {
          "bar": {
              "bar": [
                  {
                      "fields": [
                          {
                              "key": "something",
                              "things": [],
                              "value": ""
                          },
                          {
                              "key": "somethingelse",
                              "things": [],
                              "value": "1"
                          },
                          {
                              "key": "color",
                              "things": [],
                              "value": "pink"
                          }
                      ]
                  },
                  {
                      "fields": [
                          {
                              "key": "something",
                              "things": [],
                              "value": ""
                          },
                          {
                              "key": "somethingelse",
                              "things": [],
                              "value": "1"
                          },
                          {
                              "key": "color",
                              "things": [],
                              "value": "white"
                          }
                      ],
                      "id": "ALL"
                  },
                  {
                      "fields": [
                          {
                              "key": "something",
                              "things": [],
                              "value": ""
                          },
                          {
                              "key": "somethingelse",
                              "things": [],
                              "value": "1"
                          },
                          {
                              "key": "color",
                              "things": [],
                              "value": "green"
                          }
                      ],
                      "id": "1"
                  },
                  {
                      "fields": [
                          {
                              "key": "something",
                              "things": [],
                              "value": ""
                          },
                          {
                              "key": "somethingelse",
                              "things": [],
                              "value": "1"
                          },
                          {
                              "key": "color",
                              "things": [],
                              "value": "red"
                          }
                      ],
                      "id": "ALL"
                  }
              ]
          }
      }
  }
```

How do I set the value for all instances of the key named color to an empty string (`""`)? The syntax for handling this on nested arrays eludes me.

Comment: In case the start of a pure-postgres solution is helpful to you: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=0c4a9176def7bd82c3bd3bc1e300a762&hide=36. Sadly [`jsonpath` isn't implemented in cockroachdb as of v22.1.2](https://github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/issues/22513?version=v22.1) so the shredder function needs a bit of a downgrade to be compatible. General approach for shred/update/re-compose of JSON in postgres described [here](https://topanswers.xyz/databases?q=1618) and [here](https://topanswers.xyz/databases?q=1617) for next steps

Answer (score 4):

[This former question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42276968/postgres-json-update-all-array-elements/53712268#53712268) should be of help as well as the [official CockroachDB doc](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/jsonb.html) for handling JSON. Here's an example of changing key values for an array of JSON objects, though nested arrays may require a bit more work.

```
SELECT jsonb_agg(updated_jsonb)
    FROM jsonb_array_elements('[{"key": 1}, {"key": 2}]'::JSON) individual_object,
    LATERAL jsonb_set(individual_object, '{key}', '"foo"') updated_jsonb;

     
             jsonb_agg
------------------------------------
  [{"key": "foo"}, {"key": "foo"}]
```